# Problem Octane::concurrently and Auth::user()

Tags: php, laravel, ember-octane

When I call my creation method inside the observer it has an Auth::user(), when I call it through an `Octane::concurrently` it is null, if I don't use concurrently it works perfectly

ex:

```
[$contract, $contractType] = Octane::concurrently([
            fn() => Contract::create($data, $loadRelationships),
            fn() => collect(ContractTypeEnum::cases())
                ->filter(function ($enum) use ($data) {
                    return strtolower($enum->label()) === strtolower($data['contract_type']);
                })
                ->first()
                ->name,
        ]);
```

In my observer:

```
public function creating(ContractModel $contract)
    {
        // Auth::user() is null
        $contract->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
}
```

if I call create outside concurrently:

```
$contract = Contract::create($data, $loadRelationships);
```

In my observer:

```
public function creating(ContractModel $contract)
    {
        // Auth::user() is object User model
        $contract->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using concurrent mode, the task/code is handled by the job worker.

In the environment of the job worker there is no session, no user logged in and no cookies.

I suggest you send the user instance as a variable to your concurrent callback function